# Is there an standard way to access calendar events, call logs and inbox messages?

Tags: android, calendar, phone-call

I've developed an application that accesses calendar events, call logs and inbox messages by using things like this:

```
cursor = this.contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, order);
```

The app works perfectly in Galaxy SII but when I installed it in XPeria U it don't worked, probably because that phone manages calendars, calls and messages in a different way.
If I have to develop an application to each phone in the world, this is not a good business. I tried some Android classes like `CalendarContract.Events` but its API level is too hard and I don't want that because it won't work in most phones. Is there a good standard way to tho this that works on a high number of devices?
Thanks!

```
package bembibre.coolstar.windowsmobilewidget.backend;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import bembibre.coolstar.windowsmobilewidget.apiindependent.ApiIndependentCallLog;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallsContentResolver {
public static final String[] projection = {
    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    CallLog.Calls.DATE,
};

public static final String selection = "((" + CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " +
CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + ") AND NOT(" +
ApiIndependentCallLog.instance().CALLS_IS_READ + "))";

private static final int MAX_NUM_CALLS = 3;

private static final String order = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC LIMIT " + MAX_NUM_CALLS;

private ContentResolver contentResolver;

public CallsContentResolver(Context ctx) {
    this.contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
}

public void readCursor(List<Call> calls, Cursor cursor){
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String cached_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)
        );

        long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            CallLog.Calls.DATE)
        );

        Call call = new Call(cached_name, date);
        calls.add(0, call);
    }
}

public List<Call> getMissedCalls(){
    List<Call> calls = new ArrayList<Call>();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try{
        cursor = this.contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, order);
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            this.readCursor(calls, cursor);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("EXCEPCIÓN", e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return calls;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Calendar Provider (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) and Contacts Provider (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).

Comment: I have developed my code based on Calendar Provider and Contacts Provider. It works on Galaxy S2 but does not work on XPeria U. Why? Both are Android phones and my minimum API level requirements are greater than the API level of the XPeria U.

Comment: Very strange, ContentProviders are the standard way, test on others devices.

Comment: When I receive a missed call in the Galaxy, the ContentResolver, which I get in this way: `context.getContentResolver();`, gives the call to me, by querying a database. But in Xperia that database is always empty, regardless of the number of missed calls I have. If each phone uses a different database, how can I make an application that works in a wide range of Android phones? Sorry, I'm a beginner Android programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the calender event from this query where

```
long after = date.getTime();
long current = new Date().getTime();
long millisOfOne = 1000;
long millisOftwoFour = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

long millisOfTodayLast = date.getTime() + millisOftwoFour
                - millisOfOne;



Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description","dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation", "_id" },"dtstart >=" + after + " and dtstart<" + millisOfTodayLast,
            null, "dtstart ASC");
```

Comment: I've done exactly what you say. Works perfectly on Galaxy S2 but does not work on XPeria U. I don't understand. The API level of the XPeria is enough to run it but when I want to extract calendar events or calls from Android databases, exceptions are thrown, saying things like i'm out of range or like "this column does not exist"... Should not Android databases, tables and column names have the same name in ALL PHONES?? It seems that this is not true.

Comment: if Customization done with your phone then may be package name is different for that device; so you have to use their package name specifically.This coding is working on most of Android devices which having core android OS and customization not done with calender class.

Comment: This means that SONY has its own calendar and call logs applications without using those that Android provides? Then, programming an application for all phones is a nightmare... I have debugged my code to check for example why in XPeria U I can't recover missed calls in my application and it seems that XPeria U stores calls in a different way than the Galaxy S2.

Comment: No,they made some changes in core Android calender class and database..so you have to find the conditional way or find the perfect issue using debugging in SONY Xperia U.

Comment: Thank you. I think there must be a standard API to access things such the call log in all phones, regardless of manufacturer. Does someone know about it? For example, Whatsapp has to view all contacts and it works in Xperia, Galaxy S and all phones. I don't think that they have programmed the application in a different way for each phone manufacturer.

Comment: This is awful! Finally I got my application to work on Galaxy S 2 and on Xperia U. Call logs databases are slightly different in these phones. After that, I tested the application in an LG phone and it didn't work!!! What happens? I will have to make a different application for each phone brand? When I studied Android, books told that an application always or almost always will work on all phones...

Comment: There is only one thing behind this "Android customization".So you have to find the perfect reason for that; May be your code is wrong for All device  or you have to compatible your application as per the custom android for all devices.

Comment: For example, in Android documentation says that in the database table that contains the calls made or received by a phone, there is a column  named "is_read" that says if the call has been seen by the user. Well, this column doesn't exist in some phones and an Exception is thrown. So Android documentation isn't universal and is not 100% reliable. It doesn't say that the column only exists in some phones. It makes you understand that it'll be always available.